# Constant velocity achieving constant acceleration

Tags: calculus

An object is traveling at a constant speed of $25$mph, which I converted to $2200$ft/min.  It achieves a constant acceleration of $.05g$, which I assume to mean $1.6 ft/s^2$.  What distance does it cover in first 5 mins.

I use $d=v_0+v_i t + 1/2 a t^2$
=$(2200)(5) + (.5)(1.6)(5^2)$.

No where close to the answer of $83000$ ft.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: :Is the answer $85200$ ?

Comment: answer is 83,000 ft.

Comment: It’s either traveling at a constant speed or accelerating, not both. (Unless it’s moving in a circle, that is, but I don’t think that’s what whoever wrote the problem had in mind.)

Answer (score 2):

The acceleration is 1.6 ft/$s^2$ alright, but you need it in ft/min$^2$. Thus the answer is $2200 * 5 + .5 * 1.6 * 3600 * 25 = 83000$.

Comment: oh yeah.  I did the conversion for the mph but not the g .  thank you